# React Native - Keep app running when it's killed or closed in both IOS and Android

Tags: react-native, background-task

this question may seem duplicate, but I've searched a lot, but could not find any appropriate solution.

I need my socket connection to not break when user kills/closes app. It works when user presses the home button and apps goes to background. But connection breaks when user kills or closes the app. I need behavior like how chat apps like whatsapp literally work. So when I close the whatsapp, I can still receive new messages.

If anyone has found any solution for this, please share. Thank you.

Comment: The Trick is to use rather something like Headless.JS / WakeUp with Push / etc. rather than to keep your App alive, you want to wake it up when a message is incoming. But with the current mobile philosophies it can be hard to achieve an app which literally never closes.